# Water leaking from box and the relationship of volume and height.

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives, physics

Suppose we have a container that has a base of area $b$ and we fill it up with water.

Volume of water = $b \cdot h$, where $h$ is height.

Hence, $\mathrm{d}v/\mathrm{d}t = b \cdot \mathrm{d}h/\mathrm{d}t$.

The container has a small hole of area $a$ at the bottom corner and so water is constantly leaking.

From my research:

1) I found that $\mathrm{d}v/\mathrm{d}t = -a \cdot $ velocity of water.

2) Velocity = $\sqrt{2gh}$ where $g$ is the gravitational constant.

And so $\mathrm{d}v/\mathrm{d}t = -a \cdot \sqrt{2gh}$.

---

**Initially I did this:**

$\mathrm{d}v/\mathrm{d}t = -a \cdot \sqrt{2gh} = B * \mathrm{d}h/\mathrm{d}t$

$1/\sqrt{h}\mathrm{d}h = -a \sqrt{2g}/b \mathrm{d}t$

Integrate both sides

$2\sqrt{h} = -a \sqrt{2g}/b \cdot t$

$h = (a^2 \cdot g)/(2b^2) \cdot t^2$

But this doesn't make sense.

---

I realise though that the $h$ from $\mathrm{d}v/\mathrm{d}t = -a \cdot \sqrt{2gh}$ is also constantly changing but I'm still not sure what to do. I tried deriving the equation again but it did not get me anywhere.

I want to find the function how much height or volume has decreased after time t. Can someone help?

Comment: You'll also have to use the equation of continuity.

Comment: equation of continuity? can you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you know how Torricelli's law is derived?
If no, how do you know the velocity of efflux is $\sqrt{2gh}$? 
The law (for water flowing out of a container) is derived by using the equation of continuity. 
[Read here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation)

Comment: Sweet! Thank you so much

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by the comments.

Answer (score 0):

$$\huge {\rm Toricelli's\;Law}\\\large v=\sqrt{\frac{2{\rm gh}}{1-a^2/b^2}}\approx\sqrt{2{\rm gh}}\tag{$a\ll b\equiv (a/b)\to0$}$$
where $\rm a,b,v,g,h$ are cross-section area of hole ,base area of cylinder, velocity of water from hole, Acceleration due to gravity and Height of the liquid above the hole.

---

This can be derived using equation of continuity:
$$av=bV$$
where $V$ is speed of horizontal surface of water. And Bernoulli's equation:
$$\rm P+\frac12\rho v^2+\rho gh= constant$$
where $\rm P,\rho,v,g,h$ are Pressure,Density,Velocity,Acceleration due to gravity and Height of the point of the liquid where we are calculating the constant.
I believe this can also be derived by Energy Conservation.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{dV}{dt} = a \sqrt{2gy}$

$\frac{a\sqrt{2g} dt}{A} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} dy $

Upon integration we get $t=\frac{A\sqrt{2h}}{a\sqrt{g}}$

Where $a$ is cross section area of hole and $A$ is cross section of tank $h$ is the height till which water is filled.

Answer (score 0):

I use symbols $ a,A,H,T$  respectively for small hole, base area and start height in a prismatic container, total evacuation time.

The discharge rate (rate of water volume outflow) or volume flowing out per second

$$ Q = a \sqrt{2gh}= \frac{d (A\cdot h)}{dt}$$

Let $c=a \sqrt{2g}/A$

$$ c{\sqrt h}= \frac{dh}{d t} ~~ c\int_0^Tdt\to c~T=\int_0^H \frac{dh}{\sqrt h}=2 \sqrt H $$

or

$$T=\sqrt{\frac{2H}{g} } \frac{A}{a}.$$